# Add new product fields Prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop

How to add new product fields programaticly on PRESTASHOP 1.5 ?

I created these fields on SQL but I don't know how can I save it?

The fields are 3 bool, and I want to save it within a radio button option.

Answer (score 5):

You should look at Product.php, and ObjectModel.php, that correspond to the Product class and the ObjectModel class.

If you want to add fields in Product, you have to add attributes in the class, and update the $definition variable in the class by adding the definition of the attributes you added.

Regarding the radio button, it's part of the controller, take a look at AdminProductsController.php

Hope it helps,

Br,

Comment: Ok, but...for example:
I need to save a radio button that have the name "selection", and have 3 options: Yes, No, Maybe.

And I created 3 fields on sql and Product class ($definition variable), and I need to save TRUE (1) or FALSE (0) depending on radio button selection. How I can do this?

Comment: You should look at AdminProductsController, $this->fields_list. For example : 'active' => array(...)

Answer (score 0):

Mayby you will tray add new field using module ? ( This is just for EXAMPLE )

If you have fields in databes created ( in my example i use table "product_lang").

When u have skieleton module:

Create "ProductField.php" in models/

```
<?php

class ProductField extends ObjectModel
{
/** @var string Name */
public $id_product_field;

/** @var integer */
public $id_product;

/** @var string */
public $new_field;

/**
 * @see ObjectModel::$definition
 */
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'product_lang',
    'primary' => 'id_product',
    'multilang' => false,
    'fields' => array(
        'id_product' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt', 'required' => TRUE),
        'new_field' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString'),
    ),
);

public function __construct($ID_PRODUCT) {
    $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang WHERE id_product = '. (int) $ID_PRODUCT );
    $this->id_product = $ID_PRODUCT;
    $this->new_field = $result['new_field'];
}

public function update() {
    Db::getInstance()->update( 'product_lang', array( 'new_field' => $this->new_field ),  'id_product = ' . $this->id_product );
}

}
?>
```

REMEBER TO INCLUDE MODEL IN MAIN FILE.

In main file of module add method:

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params) {
$Fields = new ProductField( Tools::getValue('id_product') );
if( !empty( $Fields ) && isset( $Fields->id_product ) ) {
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'new_field' => $Fields->new_field,
    ) );
}
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/admin/admin.tpl');
}
```

Create view/admin/admin.tpl

```
<!-- New Field MODULE -->
<input type="hidden" name="submitted_tabs[]" value="productfields" />
<h4>{l s='Additional Fields' mod='productfields'}</h4>
<div class="separation"></div>
<fieldset style="border:none;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-left">
                <label>{l s='New field' mod='productfields'}<br></label>
                <p class="product_description">{l s='description of new field' mod='productfields'}</p>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="new_field" value="{if isset($new_field)}{$new_field}{/if}" />
            </td>
        <tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<div class="separation"></div>
<!-- END New Field MODULE -->
```

I hope not I have not forgotten anything. Fit only for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/kpodemski/21a37617b6b488590dc1

This is example from PrestaShop 1.5.4 but if you download 1.5.6 and change informations.tpl to newer version it's should work fine.